# How to hide/ignore a field in swagger docs but set via spec/jolt file in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, swagger-ui, jolt

While writing an **API** that takes a model such as:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Plan
{
  @NotBlank
  private String param1;
  private String param2;
}
```

I want to hide/ignore this *param2* in Swagger UI. I have used **@JsonIgnore**, this works for swagger UI but it considers my param2 as null when it is mapped in a spec file.

I have also tried using **@ApiModelProperty(accessMode = ApiModelProperty.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)**, **@ApiParam(hidden=true)** it sets the param2 via jolt spec file but doesn't hide them in Swagger UI.

In short, these are the 2 things that I am trying to achieve:

1. Hide field param2 in Swagger UI.
2. At the same time, set param2 via jolt mapping in the spec file.

I have tried https://www.baeldung.com/spring-swagger-hide-field these solutions and none of them seems to work. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix dependency**

The dependency I was using was incompatible with some versions. After some research, I found a dependency that can hide a model attribute in Swagger-UI but doesn't interrupt any other flows (i.e: Mapping via jolt file). In your **pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**Hide parameter via @Schema**

In your model class, import:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
```

and above the parameter, write:

```
@Schema(hidden = true)
```

The **model class** would look like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Plan
{
  @NotBlank
  private String param1;
  @Schema(hidden = true)
  private String param2;
}
```

This would hide the *param2* in Swagger-UI and you can still have access to setters/getters, and your other flows will remain uninterrupted.